# Input Clear Button for Textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Updating what has worked and the current issue:

I have 1 clear button beside each field. Each clear button works. The problem is after clearing both fields, when selecting another file from the dropdown, it only populates the text field with the file name and does not display the contents in the second textarea until refreshing the page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="EDIT" /><input type="hidden" name="Selection"  id="Selection" value="-1"><div><font color=#2F6054>Below is the list of your saved codes. To view or delete your codes, select it from the list.</font></font></div><p>
<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList">
<?php
   $directory = $directory = 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
   $filesContents = Array();
   $files = scandir( $directory ) ;

   foreach( $files as $file )
 {
   if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
 {
   $filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory , $file);
   echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
 }
 }
 ?>
</select><p>
        <font color=#2F6054><font size=4>Enter Codes Here</font></font>
        <form method="post" action="/evo/avsaveprocess.php">

            <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="SAVE" />
            <input type="hidden" name="CodeId" id="CodeId" value="0" />
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Description:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="CodeDescription" size="40" maxlength="50" id="CodeName" value="" /></td>
                    <td><button type="reset" class="clear-tn" value="Clear"></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Code:</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea rows="10" style="width:99%" name="Code" id="CodeValue"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

function code:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('.clear-btn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');
   });
});
</script>
```

**Edited to show current working code**

**Editing to show on change script at the bottom of my form for the dropdown**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// apply a change event
$('#CodeList').change(function() {
  // update input box with the currently selected value
    $('#CodeName').val($(this).val());
    $.get( '<? echo $directory ?>' + '/' + $('#CodeName').val(), function( data ) {
        $( "#CodeValue" ).val( data );
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: A couple things look off here. Where's the RESET button, and where's the javascript? Then, what's with the `input` and `select` sitting out in the open  before the `form`?

Comment: I didn't put the reset button back in that I was using and the input and select is sitting outside because that is a dropdown list that pulls files from the server that populates the form after information from the form is saved.

Comment: edited to add the reset button I was using which obviously only resets the first text area i wasn't able to figure out how to write it to do both.

Comment: Please add the JS as well to better understand the problem.

Comment: I apologize I am cleaning up my question and coding I forgot i was working with clear-btn and will edit things and my question.

Comment: Yes, you don't need of javascript or Jquery to reset and clear the fields. HTML inputs are enough to do that. Go through these link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Going through the answers, conversations and fiddles so far, I arrive at this conclusion. @RobertEttinger you need to CLARIFY the problem once more. And guys, please let's first UNDERSTAND his problems accurately. Do you have SEVERAL textareas on your form, and are you trying to clear EACH ONE with a "Clear" button beside it?

Comment: I apologize @Ifedi if things got confusing. I was attempting multiple tries at this. Yes, now I have 1 clear button beside each field. Each clear button works. The problem is after clearing both fields, when selecting another file from the dropdown, it only populates the text field with the file name and does not display the contents in the second textarea until refreshing the page.

Comment: Shall we troubleshoot? In your code, just before `$( "#CodeValue" ).text( data );`, add this: `alert(data);`. What does it show? (I couldn't use your fiddle because the `select` is not populated.)

Comment: It gives an alert popup that says "testing" which is the contents of the file I selected.

Comment: To clarify, it shows the file information in the alert popup of the file selected, it just doesn't put it back into the textarea like it does before clearing the field.

Comment: Then try : `$( "#CodeValue" ).val( data );` in place of `$( "#CodeValue" ).text( data );`

Comment: That Sir. Was the missing link. The value that was holding it up that was missed. Thank you, so very very much for the continued assist. I now have two solutions thanks to all of you guys I can go with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change type attribute "button" to "reset".

```
<button type="reset" class="clear-btn">Clear</button>
```

Try below working fiddle as per your requirement.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/t7gkr8rk/1/

Comment: Thank you Amit this works however I have two of these buttons which I'm editing in now and only the first one functions.

Comment: @ Ganesh I wrote my question wrong, and had tried a different type="reset" not this one, Amit's answer is right but only one button functions.

Comment: @RobertEttinger is second button is submit button?

Comment: there is a clear button I was trying to put after each field, to clear each field, and at the bottom of the form, yes, there is a submit button for when users input info and hit submit, it saves it, then they can populate those fields from a dropdown with that saved information (or from other files they have saved)

Comment: Amit, that ALMOST did it. I can use the buttons to clear both fields now, however when I go back to the dropdown list and select the next file, it only populates the name (first text area) and doesn't display the file contents like it should in the second box. However, I believe I can have my users work around this, it returns functionality on reloading of the page. Hopefully I explained that right.

Comment: Hmm. @RobertEttinger, the Clear buttons on this fiddle are NOT clearing the `textarea`. I thought I required that (even as the JS code would imply). The problem is, your textarea is on the next row and isn't captured in your jQuery object. Anyway if it works for you!

Comment: @Amit. Using `<button type="reset" class="clear-btn">Clear</button>` is meant for return ALL FIELDS ON THE FORM (including hidden fields) to their default values. Using this markup, only to coerce it later in JS with `preventDefault` seems semantically wrong. You do not need the `type="reset"` at all, and the code should work.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo: Yes.technically I agree with you. The code provided by amit does not technically accepted

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo I already removed type reset from mentioned fiddle ie. http://fiddle.jshell.net/t7gkr8rk/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below link, it works without javascript or jquery. Just simple HTML

```
<form>
     <input type="reset" />
     <input type="submit" />
     <input type="text" />
   <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rrm6357j/)

Comment: thank you nadeem not sure what I'm doing wrong when I enter in <input type="reset" /> and press it, it only resets the first text field and not both.

Comment: @RobertEttinger: You have not written the html tags porperly. Also your `form` tag is not closed. Check the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/qfah9nq0/3/ It is working now

Comment: I apologize Nadeem I am checking out your fiddle, my form is however closed in my codes I forgot to copy it.

Comment: I input your code Nadeem as is, and for some reason, it still only clears the first text area. I do have a script for an onchange element beneath the form to populate the boxes when the dropdown list changes not sure if that has anything to do with it but it works in your fiddle however it doesn't on my page, or if it has to do with the information in the text boxes being populated from the dropdown.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p4tdyws0/  this fiddle shows all of my coding on the page for the entire form. there's nothing else other then art code in there for the page the form sits in but I can copy and paste the entirety of the page if you need more then that.

Comment: @RobertEttinger: Not sure about your dropdownlist, but all other inputs are working. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/p4tdyws0/1/

Comment: the dropdown list works, and that populates both fields, its just that clear button for some reason does not clear out the textarea that is displaying the file contents pulled from the dropdown.

Comment: @RobertEttinger: Did you checked my latest fiddle.?? it is also clearing the Textarea..

Comment: I did, yes, but for some reason it was only clearing one field still however using both buttons and the scripting @Amit posted I'm able to clear both fields, just not populate one of them again until refresh.

Comment: @RobertEttinger: you are asking many things in one post. Please ask the new question if you any doubts. Your question was clearing fields and it is working

Comment: That is very true. Thank you nadeem I will mark the answer and ask a new question. Thank you guys for all of your help.